# How to change the title position for list of figures and table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, positioning, tocloft, titletoc

I have used a style for the toc and lof title but the position is a little bit far from the top of the page and i want to make it more closer to the header

Here is a complete example

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,final]{report}
% Pour une impression recto verso, utilisez plutôt ce documentclass :
%\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,final]{article}

\usepackage{tabto} 
\usepackage{mathptmx} % text new roman font
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}    
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[french]{varioref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amssymb}
 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{courier}
 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % load a font with all the characters

%\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{arabtex}  % caption must be loaded before arabtex
\usepackage{utf8}

% add an extra subsection
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[]{titlesec} 
\definecolor{yourcolor}{HTML}{008bb2}

\colorlet{chpnumbercolor}{black}
\makeatletter
\let\oldl@chapter\l@chapter
\def\l@chapter#1#2{\oldl@chapter{#1}{\textcolor{chpnumbercolor}{#2}}}

\let\old@dottedcontentsline\@dottedtocline
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
\old@dottedcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{{\textcolor{chpnumbercolor}{#5}}}}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\color{yourcolor}}
  {\filleft\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\chaptertitlename\hspace*{2mm}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-.6ex]current bounding box.center)}]
    \node[fill=yourcolor,circle,text=white] {\thechapter};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule[3pt]\vspace*{5ex}\huge\sffamily\itshape}
  []

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\color{yourcolor}}
  {}
  {1ex}
  {\vspace*{1ex}\huge\sffamily\itshape\center}
  []        
   \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}

%command to print the acutal minitoc
\newcommand{\printmyminitoc}{%
    \noindent\hspace{-2cm}\vspace{-2cm}%
    \colorlet{chpnumbercolor}{white}%
}
    
 
\newcommand{\mychapter}[2]{
    \setcounter{chapter}{#1}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \chapter*{#2}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}
}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}

%\usepackage{tocloft}                                              
%\renewcommand\cftbeforetoctitleskip{-2cm}
%\renewcommand\cftbeforeloftitleskip{-2cm}
%\renewcommand\cftbeforelottitleskip{-2cm}

\begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
  \listoffigures
   \chapter{Chapitre 1: Etude et analyse}
  \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: Before]

After using

```
 \usepackage{tocloft}                                              
 \renewcommand\cftbeforetoctitleskip{-2cm}
 \renewcommand\cftbeforeloftitleskip{-2cm}
 \renewcommand\cftbeforelottitleskip{-2cm}
```

[image: after]

the two titles are overlapping and the style previously defined have changed but instead i want just to change the position and keep the font size /color

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to move that `tocloft`  stuff to the top?

Comment: You're preamble is a mess - loading some packages twice and what's worse, `hyperref` somewhere in between, but the real issue is using `titletoc` and `tocloft` -- those two packages just conflict!

Comment: @Johannes_B tried but gives the same results

Comment: @ChristianHupfer you're right but , the package tocloft was commented  , i removed the duplicate too ... then found a simple solution

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to change the titleFormat using a negative value for vspace like below:

```
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\color{yourcolor}}
  {}
  {1ex}
  {\vspace{-20ex}\huge\sffamily\itshape\center}
  []        
   \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
```